# How can I find out objectType of Account

Tags: apex, describesobject

I have the following code :

```
Schema.SObjectType objectType = sObjects.get(0).getSObjectType();
```

I'm trying to write an IF statement to check if the result of objectType is specific object such as Account.

I have written something like this :

```
if(objectType == Schema.SObjectType.Account)
```

But this does not work with the Following Error :

> Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Schema.SObjectType,
>   Schema.DescribeSObjectResult

So My question is what Comparison argument should i use to validate 'Account' object results?
Thanks for any quick help..

Comment: Interesting that `SObjectType.Account` compiles and returns the same data that the documented `Account.SObjectType.getDescribe()` returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get sObjectType of Account, comparison statement in above code should be changed to `if(objectType == Schema.Account.sObjectType)`

Comment: *Schema* is optional, unless there's a class named Account.

Comment: And you'd probably need to be smoking something pretty strong to name your class 'Account'

Comment: Yeah naming a class that would be crazy. But not a variable.

Answer (score 3):

I go even more brief:

```
if (objectType == Account.sObjectType)
```

Only downside is it won't work if you have a variable named `Account`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a` is an sObject, for Account, you could do something like this:

```
if('account` == String.valueOf(a.getSobjectType()).toLowerCase())
```

Comment: string == is already case insensitive, so don't waste time there, *and* there's more efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: String typing? I try to avoid it when I can.

Comment: Thnx guys. Am always learning from what you and others post! :)